# Appending divs to html body at runtime are overlapping each other

Tags: css, angularjs

[Here is the working plunker which is almost implemented](https://plnkr.co/edit/GSqHdNeNhLFrePTIJJHY?p=preview). The issue is that the chat divs are getting added to the body at runtime using `$compile` but they are inheriting same css class and so overlapping each other, i.e:

```
 .chat-window{
            bottom:0;
            position:fixed;
            float:right;
            margin-left:10px;
  }
```

What css do I need to add , so that they open side-wise rather than overlapping each other.

Little help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hyzfQYw1oqDCf12yK605?p=preview) which calculates box count and accordingly provides its position

```
var setPixel = function (chatWindowNumber) {
            if (chatWindowNumber > 0) {
                return (chatWindowNumber * 410) + 'px';
            } else {
                return 0;
    }

  };
```

and append like below:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('main-html-body')).append(
      $compile("<div chat-box \n\
                    id=" + scope.user + "\n\
                     class='row chat-window col-xs-5 col-md-3' \n\
                       incoming-msg='incomingMsg' \n\
                         open-chat-user-list='openChatUserList' \n\
                            user='user' \n\
                           count='count' style='position: fixed;bottom:0; right: " + setPixel(scope.count.p) + "'></div>"
         )(scope)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a wrapper around the chat windows and fix position that, then float the chat window div's themselves? Something like (untested):

**1. Fixed wrapper with floating children**

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat-wrapper">
   <div class="chat-window"></div>
   <div class="chat-window"></div>
   <div class="chat-window"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chat-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.chat-window {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**2. Flexbox solution**

**CSS**

```
.chat-wrapper {
   position: fixed; 
   bottom: 0;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: you beat me to the answer but here's basically the same thing... doesn't work exactly as expected with 3 windows but can easily modify the spacing. https://plnkr.co/edit/dROkDuSHZzxTh1PyxVYc?p=preview

Comment: @jusopi:  pivemi: Well, i tried that something like that before but it changes the behavior when minimizing diff chat windows when we open all of them. have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/ShoBFlUuC3el7HCsU09c?p=preview

Comment: Okay. What is the behaviour you want to achieve?

Comment: @pivemi: It should minimize to the bottom of the browser. If u open all three chat windows, they will minimize but not to the bottom of the page. Let me know if you want screenshot to get better understanding

Comment: https://s9.postimg.org/wc5iit2m7/multiu_chat.jpg . Please see USER2 and USER3 chat